# How to make cross-platform makefile: read variable in Windows / Linux

Tags: linux, windows, makefile, alembic

The code below (in Makefile) works fine for linux, but I want to make universal makefile for linux and windows.

```
migrations:
    @read -p "Enter migration message: " message; \
    alembic revision --autogenerate --message "$$message"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What is the problem with running it in Windows?

Comment: It's always a very bad idea, even on POSIX systems like GNU/Linux, to have a Makefile recipe that reads from standard input.  Users should provide data via command line variable settings, like `make MESSAGE='this is my  message'`

Comment: Line endings are different for text files on Windows.